# Django - like unlike system - how changing the button color for unliking?

Tags: python, django

Here is my follow/unfollow system. If user clic first, he adds if he clics seconds time he removes. What's the best way to change the color of the text of the button? After user clics for the first time?

user/views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/cooker/login')
def FollowView(request, pk):
    userprofile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user_id=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        _followed = request.user in userprofile.follow.all()
        if _followed:
            userprofile.follow.remove(request.user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')) 
        else:
            userprofile.follow.add(request.user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))      
        
    @property
    def total_follow(self):
        return self.follow.count()
```

Here is my template:
user/template/exemple.html

```
<div class="col-sm-4">  
         <form action="{% url 'user:follow_public' current_user.pk %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" name="user_id" value="{{ current_user.id }}" style="width: 100%;background: #ff6670;padding: 10px;border-radius: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px;outline:none;">Follow {{current_user.username}}</button>
         </form>
         </div>
```

**UPDATE : SOLVE SOLUTION for my wishlist (just change the name of variable)**

```
{% if post in user.userprofile.wishlist.all %}
color: #ff4955;
{% else %}color: #fff;
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Javascript is enough?

Comment: I've tried something like that for my wishlist (variable change): {% if post in userprofile.wishlist.all %}color: #ff4955;{% else %}color: #fff;{% endif %}. but that's does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Just change the button's style attribute.